# Convert base 64 to audio Mp3 Format on PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have an "audio" tag with the script (actually a plugin) that receives and saves it as base64. And this works okay.

I am trying to alter the script to send the base64 into the server and convert it to mp3 and display the recorded audio in the page.

This is what I have done so far.
Script to save file through ajax:

```
$(document).on("click", "#download:not(.disabled)", function(){

    Fr.voice.export(function(url){
      //$("<a href='"+url+"' download='MyRecording.wav'></a>")[0].click();
      var src = url;
      $.ajax({
            url: $("#base_url").val() + "ajax/saveRecordedVoice",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"record_src": src},
            success: function(result){
                alert(result);
            }

      });
    }, "base64");
    restore();
  });
```

PHP Script to Convert and Save File:

```
public function saveRecordedVoice()
    {

      $audio = $_POST['record_src'];
      $decoded = base64_decode($audio);
      $file_location = "assets/records/recorded_audio.mp3";

      $success = file_put_contents($file_location, $decoded);

      if($success){
         echo "File Saved";
      }else{
        echo "Uh-uh!";
      }

    }
```

The file was successfully saved as .mp3 in my server but when I try to play it manually, Media player says:

[image]

Comment: I think you actually want .export(stuff, "mp3"), which exports base64 encoded mp3s.

Comment: have tried it, but still not working.

Comment: Going to have to describe what you tried, what you got and how you determined it wasn't working. Might help to put up your received file on dropbox somewhere, too.

Comment: you mean the saved file?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which plugin you're using to capture the audio, it's hard to really be sure. However i assume that the:

```
//$("<a href='"+url+"' download='MyRecording.wav'></a>")[0].click();
```

actually worked before, meaning that whatever audio you're receiving is direct sound.

Mp3 however is an encoded format, and as such, your media player is probably failing, trying to decode unencoded audio.

Try changing the output ending:

```
$file_location = "assets/records/recorded_audio.wav";
```

and see if those files will play for you.

If that does not solve it, you should output the "url" you send as data, to see if it sends unwanted markers/headers along.

Comment: They're using this https://subinsb.com/html5-record-mic-voice
Pretty sure that export option doesn't actually encode to mp3.

Comment: @Avenar: I tried to change to recorded_audio.wav and another media player error occurs.

Comment: @pvg: ah yeah, i see. It does say "Now supports converting WAV audio to MP3 which will help reduce the size of recorded file.". However, reading this plugin and its manual makes it clear that to get mp3 content, he needs to change `}, "base64");` to `}, "mp3");` in the JS, and then not base64_decode in the php.

Comment: @Avenar the docs I saw suggested the mp3 is actually base64 encoded _before_ any encoding done by the POST.

Comment: `Fr.voice.export(function(mp3){
  console.log(mp3); // The MP3 Data encoded in Base64`
So you probably still need the base64_decode.